# Is it possible to bulkly remove faulty pages from google search console?

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, hacked-site

Due to error in my sitemap after a hack event, so many non-existing pages were listed in my site map which google tried to index them. Currently these pages are not present in my sitemap anymore, but they are list in list of `not-found` or `access denied` reports of google search console as shown in this picture.

[image]

Are there any remedies to this situation?

Since there are many of these pages (About 570K+16K), I cannot remove them one by one. So I want to know if there are any faster ways to remove whole of them instead of manually removing them one by one (which seems impossible).

Comment: *Are there any remedies to this situation?* Yes. Time. Otherwise, there is no way to hurry Google up. If the URLs have a pattern that can be used within robots.txt, then that may be an option. Also, please understand, that Search Console is notoriously slow and behind reality. While it will take quite a while to remove the bad URLs, months likely, Search Console will be disappointing when the reality is somewhat different. These are just notices for your sake and not a problem. It is common to feel compelled to fix everything when you do not have to. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will eventually stop reporting them, but they will still be on record. The good news is it has no negative consequences. One option is to change them to 410 status, so they get reported slightly differently, and may disappear quicker.